# How to resolve problem with Cookie JSESSIONID in Oracle ADF?

Tags: java, oracle, security, oracle-adf, crlf-vulnerability

I have an application written in Oracle Adf. This application has a vulnerability

> "The timestamp was disclosed by the application/web server - Unix"

The problem is in this Set-Cookie line:

`JSESSIONID=DEggiV29rBcanONesUZsMKn7taA5hOIDieH35_LtDVs4Cyahbb5C!1759858802; domain=;samesite=strict; path=/; secure; HttpOnly`
namely in the number after the exclamation mark (!)`1759858802`.
How to remove it or how to solve this problem? Help me, please!

I haven't found any steps that could solve this problem.